# Filter iterator with list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to filter a `itertool.combinations` object with a list of elements.

This is the iterator:

```
from itertools import combinations 

items = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']
comb = combinations(items, 3)
```

Now, I can print the list of combinations with

```
for i in comb:
    print(i)
```

What I need is a list with all combination where `['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']` are involves.

I tried to convert something like this

```
if 'm1' in ('m1', 'm2', 'm4'):
...     print('ok')
... 
ok
```

into this

```
ms1 = list(filter(lambda x: 'm1' in x, comb)) // empty list
ms2 = list(filter(lambda x: ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'] in x, comb)) // empty list
```

What I need is to get all combinations

Comment: Well `combinations(items, 3)` will return tuples with 3 elements so it will be impossible to find 5 elements. Besides, `ms1` works just fine. Make sure you haven't exhausted the `comb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a list of only those combinations that include any one of the values in the target list of items (`['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']`), then using set intersection may be appropriate.

Example:

```
from itertools import combinations 

items = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'b10', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']
item_combinations = combinations(items, 3)

target_items = {'m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'}
target_item_combinations = [
    one_combination
    for one_combination in item_combinations
    if set(one_combination) & target_items
]
```